# Delete and not in

Tags: mysql

```
$this->_bdd->exec('DELETE FROM episodes
    WHERE  number_episode = ".$idEpisode"
    NOT IN (SELECT id 
            FROM (SELECT id 
                  FROM episodes) AS episodes_sub_id 
            WHERE id = ".$id")');
```

I find it difficult to deal whith DELETE and condition; The aim here was to
 **delete all the number-episode** :number_episode = ".$idEpisode")
**except** the one having a particular id :NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM episodes) AS episodes_sub_id WHERE id = ".$id")');

There is no error message but it has no effect at all in my db (bdd). So something must be wrong in my request.

Here is the table :

```
   CREATE TABLE `episodes` (
       `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `number_episode` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `title_episode` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
       `text_episode` longtext NOT NULL,
       `status_episode` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
       `date_episode_optional` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would be curious to know how to deal with this sort of matter if one day I am faced to it. Thanks for your comments !

Comment: you forgot `AND id` before your `NOT IN`

Comment: One. Your code is prone to MySQL injection...Two. Still using MyISAM now a days?.. looks to me you are missing a `AND id` in the WHERE statement.`[...] WHERE  number_episode = ".$idEpisode"
  AND  id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [....]`

Comment: No message  error with your code but it still have no effect in my db

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?:

```
$this->_bdd->exec("DELETE FROM episodes
    WHERE  number_episode = ". $idEpisode ." AND id != ". $id);
```

Comment: lots of error messages with this code : "Notice: Undefined variable: id" and "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près de '' à la ligne 2" and  " PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près de '' à la ligne 2" concerning this part of the code : WHERE  number_episode = ". $idEpisode ." AND id != ". $id);

Comment: @Bened make sure that $id is defined and has a value. The error is saying id is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `AND` operator with your conditions in your query.
Try something like this:

```
$this->_bdd->exec("DELETE FROM episodes
WHERE  number_episode = ".$idEpisode." AND id 
NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM episodes) AS episodes_sub_id WHERE id = ".$id."));
```